# How to get Facebook public data (public posts) only in english language?

Tags: c#, facebook

currently I am working on an app and I need to get Facebook public post data, as Facebook give access to its public data through Graph API. I can access them through Facebook API in C#. But the problem is, when I retrieve this public data, it give me only in German language posts (may be because I am in Germany). But I wanted to access the comments in English language or other countries then how it can be possible?

Any suggestion or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you access the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that they are simply respecting the Accept-Language header you send them.  Add a header to your request setting "Accept-Language" to "en-US" and you should get back US English results.

EDIT:  correction... looking at the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/) you need to add a "locale" querystring to the URL you request from them.  The example given is "https://graph.facebook.com/645752348782873?access_token=$APPID|$APPSECRET&locale=en_US"